# Scraping with R, how to extract var

Tags: r, screen-scraping

```
require(httr)
require(XML)
basePage <- "http://bet.hkjc.com/"
h <- handle(basePage)
GET(handle = h)
res <- GET(handle = h, path = "racing/pages/odds_wp.aspx?date=27-09-2017&venue=HV&raceno=2")
resXML <- htmlParse(content(res, as = "text"))
```

I used the above code to scrape a aspx. website. It returned with a bunch of text. However I am interested only in getting "var infoDivideByRace", "var scratchList". May I ask how do I extract these two variables and turn them into column data? thanks! some of the returns are as follows:

```
var poolSellStatus = '1@@@@@@;WIN;PLA;W-P;QIN;QPL;QQP;TRI;DBL;TCE;F-F;QTT;CWA;'.split('@@@');
var poolSellStatus_bak = '1@@@@@@;WIN;PLA;W-P;QIN;QPL;QQP;TRI;DBL;TCE;F-F;QTT;CWA;'.split('@@@');
var winOddsByRace = '175852@@@@@@WIN;1=3.6=1;2=4.7=0;3=43=0;4=11=0;5=29=0;6=9.4=0;7=4.6=0;8=11=0;9=52=0;10=82=0;11=52=0;12=8.6=0#PLA;1=1.4=1;2=2.0=0;3=6.0=0;4=3.5=0;5=6.2=0;6=2.6=0;7=2.0=0;8=4.2=0;9=7.9=0;10=11=0;11=8.4=0;12=2.5=0'.split('@@@');
var multiRacePoolsStr = '@@@DBL#;1,2;2,3;3,4;4,5;5,6;6,7;7,8@@@TBL#;6,7,8@@@D-T#;3,4;6,7@@@T-T#;4,5,6@@@6UP#;3,4,5,6,7,8';
var fieldSize = 'HV;12;12;12;12;12;12;12;12';
var fieldSizeWithReserve = 'HV;12;12;12;12;12;12;12;12';
var reserveList = 'HV';
var scratchList = 'HV';
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest or the most appropriate way is to use Phantomjs or selenium. If not, `Regex` and `rvest` work around.

```
library(rvest)

basePage <- "http://bet.hkjc.com/"

ss <- paste0(basePage,path)

path = "racing/pages/odds_wp.aspx?date=27-09-2017&venue=HV&raceno=2"

scripts <- read_html(ss, encoding = 'utf8') %>% 
    html_nodes("script") %>% html_text(trim=TRUE)

new <- scripts[grepl('var scratchList =|var infoDivideByRace = ',scripts)]

value1 <- str_replace_all(strsplit(str_extract(new,regex('var scratchList = (.*?);')), split=' ')[[1]][4],";|'",'')    
value2 <- str_replace_all(strsplit(str_extract(new,regex('var infoDivideByRace = (.*?);')),split=' ')[[1]][4],";|'",'')

value1
#[1] "HV"

value2
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate option using the V8 package:

```
library(rvest)
library(stringi)
library(purrr)
library(V8)
```

Get the page content you specified:

```
pg <- read_html("http://bet.hkjc.com/racing/pages/odds_wp.aspx?date=27-09-2017&venue=HV&raceno=2", encoding = "UTF-8")
```

Extract script tags that contain your target variables, convert the script tag to text, split into a character vector, keep only the `var` lines:

```
html_nodes(pg, xpath=".//script[contains(., 'infoDivideByRace')]") %>% 
  html_text() %>% 
  stri_split_lines() %>% 
  flatten_chr() %>% 
  keep(stri_detect_regex, "^var") -> script_txt
```

Initialise the V8 javascript engine:

```
ctx <- v8()
```

Let it parse the javascript and create the data:

```
ctx$eval(script_txt)
```

Retrieve the data (`infoDivideByRace` has 2 blank array elements so we ignore them):

```
grep("^$", ctx$get('infoDivideByRace'), value=TRUE, invert=TRUE)
## [1] STACKOVERFLOW'S SPAM PROTECTION WON'T LET ME PASTE THIS CONTENT

ctx$get('scratchList')
[1] "HV"
```

Comment: the above doesn't work...
it returned: Error in flatten_chr(.) : could not find function "flatten_chr"

Comment: I forgot a `library(purrr)` (which I've added to the post)